# why tcpdf adds extra margin left?

Tags: tcpdf

[image]

the html being rendered is very simple:

```
    <div>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo "Date/Time"; ?> <?php echo date('d:m:Y'); ?></b></td>
            <td><b>line 1</b></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo "Date/Time"; ?> <?php echo date('d:m:Y'); ?></b></td>
            <td><b>line 2</b></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the <div> tags?

Comment: @L.Herrera removing the div tags fixed the issue..